# How to detect mouse inactivity

Tags: arch-linux, mouse

I want to automatically dim keyboards light when its been inactive for some time. How can I detect inactivity time? I use archlinux, btw.

Comment: look at the design of a custom screen saver perhaps

Answer (score 2):

On Debian-based systems, there's a `xprintidle` command in the `xprintidle` package (from https://github.com/g0hl1n/xprintidle/) that prints the idle time in milliseconds on stdout.

```
$ sleep 2; xprintidle
1925
```

If you `ltrace` it, you'll see it uses `XScreenSaverQueryExtension()`, `XScreenSaverQueryInfo()` API like in other answers though [also adds some workarounds to specific issues in corner cases with some servers](https://github.com/g0hl1n/xprintidle/blob/a3037532bc7c24f50f5a7598755e562d4f4bfcf6/xprintidle.c#L142).

Comment: does not work with Wayland unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

Compiling and running this gets idle time in miliseconds

```
#include <X11/extensions/scrnsaver.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    Display *dpy = XOpenDisplay(NULL);

    if (!dpy) {
        return(1);
    }

    XScreenSaverInfo *info = XScreenSaverAllocInfo();
    XScreenSaverQueryInfo(dpy, DefaultRootWindow(dpy), info);
    printf("%u\n", info->idle);

      return(0);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is also implemented in C (with Makefile) at https://github.com/mjml/xidle.

It will provide hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds of idle time for shell scripts, with units/denominations selected by optional switches.